# PyQt QSortProxyModel - Does a column need to be displayed to be sortable?

Tags: python, pyqt

I am trying to make a tree view where the underlying nodes have many attributes (~9) and have been studying the PyQt5 examples supplied with the examples. However the examples and search hits fail to answer my following question. First my goal:

I simply want to give a view on a tree via a column of node names and want to be able to sort on different attributes/columns. I e.g. tried to use

```
        myView.sortByColumn(8, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
```

to sort by the 8th attribute of my model

```
def data(self, index, role):
[...]
        elif index.column() == 8:

            return node.status
[...]
```

however upon only showing the first column (node names) in the view

```
def columnCount(self, parent):
    """
    in: QModelIndex
    out: int
    """
    N = 1

    return N
```

did not see a sorted result in my view.

Upon changing the columnCount to 9, the view was sorted by the 8th column in return for 8 columns I did not want to see in my view...

Do you have to display a column to be able to sort by it? If not, could you give an explanation or small example of how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem after trying out some things:

It turns out, you have to make sure that the columnCount N of the model is large enough s.t. the column j can be used by the proxy model to sort! I.e. N >  j.

The columnCount of a custom (!) proxy model can then be used to display the desired number of columns.

```
class MySortFilterProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MySortFilterProxyModel, self).__init__(parent)

    def columnCount(self, parent=None):
        return 1

class MyTreeModel(QtCore.QAbstractItemModel):

    def __init__(self, root, parent=None):
        """
        in: Node, Qobject
        """

        super(MyTreeModel, self).__init__(parent)

        self._root = root
        self.parent = parent


    def columnCount(self, parent):
        """
        in: QModelIndex
        out: int
        """
        return 9

        [...]
```

This off course makes sense once you remember that the proxy model "views" the model i.e. only knows the columns made public by the model.

Hope this perhaps saves someone else a few minutes of trial and error.